# Check if not nil and not empty in Rails shortcut?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a show page for my Users and each attribute should only be visible on that page, if it is not nil and not an empty string. Below I have my controller and it is quite annoying having to write the same line of code `@user.city != nil && @user.city != ""` for every variable. I am not too familiar with creating my own methods, but can I somehow create a shortcut to do something like this: `@city = check_attr(@user.city)`? Or is there a better way to shorten this procedure?

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show 
  @city = @user.city != nil && @user.city != ""
  @state = @user.state != nil && @user.state != ""
  @bio = @user.bio != nil && @user.bio != ""
  @contact = @user.contact != nil && @user.contact != ""
  @twitter = @user.twitter != nil && @user.twitter != ""
  @mail = @user.mail != nil && @user.mail != ""
end
```

Answer (score 225, accepted):

There's a method that does this for you:

```
def show
  @city = @user.city.present?
end
```

The `present?` method tests for not-`nil` plus has content. Empty strings, strings consisting of spaces or tabs, are considered not present.

Since this pattern is so common there's even a shortcut in ActiveRecord:

```
def show
  @city = @user.city?
end
```

This is roughly equivalent.

As a note, testing vs `nil` is almost always redundant. There are only two logically false values in Ruby: `nil` and `false`. Unless it's possible for a variable to be literal `false`, this would be sufficient:

```
if (variable)
  # ...
end
```

This is preferable to the usual `if (!variable.nil?)` or `if (variable != nil)` stuff that shows up occasionally. Ruby tends to wards a more reductionist type of expression.

One reason you'd want to compare vs. `nil` is if you have a tri-state variable that can be `true`, `false` or `nil` and you need to distinguish between the last two states.

Comment: Note, as of Ruby 2.3.0 you can get rid of many redundant nil checks using the lonely operator, something like `if @user && @user.authenticated` can simply become `if @user&.authenticated`

Comment: Another reason you'd want to do `if object.present?` over `if object` is if you later wrap the object in a decorator, the result would change unless you used `.present?`. https://philihp.com/2018/prefer-if-object-present-over-if-object.html

Answer (score 16):

You can use [.present?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) which comes included with ActiveSupport.

```
@city = @user.city.present?
# etc ...
```

---

You could even write it like this

```
def show
  %w(city state bio contact twitter mail).each do |attr|
    instance_variable_set "@#{attr}", @user[attr].present?
  end
end
```

---

It's worth noting that if you want to test if something is blank, you can use `.blank?` (this is the opposite of `.present?`)

Also, don't use `foo == nil`. Use `foo.nil?` instead.

Comment: @Mayank, the OP is setting an instance variable to `true`/`false` value. `reciever.present?` will return true if `receiver` is a non-empty value. Please see the docs I linked for further explanation.

Comment: thanks i got your point but i am not able to understand how instance_variable_set "@#{attr}", @user[attr].present? will work..?

Comment: @Mayank, `instance_variable_set("@foo", "bar")` is the same as `@foo =  "bar"`. It's just a programmatic way of setting instance variables ^^

Comment: okz thanks now i have understand...but one more thing what javascript:atob("bmFreW90b0BnbWFpbC5jb20="); means ?

Comment: Mayank, run it in a javascript console to find out!

Comment: javascript console where..?

Comment: @Mayank, there's one built into almost every web browser. Otherwise you can try this one: http://repl.it/languages/JavaScript

Comment: Glad you mentioned `.blank?` too